# How to set up precision by default?

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I have a table computing many numbers with large precision. Because of this, probably, Mathematica consumes a lot of RAM. Is it possible to restrict the precision in any calculations by default (globally) by n digits?

Comment: Seems easier to use `SetPrecision` on your table inputs instead. Would that not work?

Comment: Even if you restrict Precision, calculations with machine numbers are still done with the full amount of binary digits.

Comment: @MarcoB : in my case, RAM is consumed during the calculations of table.

Comment: @John Could you show a sample of one such calculation then, or an equivalent minimal working example?

Comment: How big is the array and how much memory is it using?

Comment: @mikado : 16.8 billion rows, each having 10 columns. It uses approx 16 Gb of RAM.

Comment: @JohnTaylor - that doesn't sound possible.  It's less than 1 bit per element of your table.

Comment: @mikado : please find the illustrative example in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263478/how-to-fix-mathematica-crashing-in-the-following-case