# How to fix Mathematica crashing in the following case?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review, crash, broken-code

I have a problem with Mathematica when trying to glue two tables together.

The tables have the form

```
tab2={{d1,f1,g1,...},{d2,f2,g2,...},...}
tab1 = {{a1,b1,c1},{a1,b1,c2},...,{a1,b2,c1},{a1,b2,c2},...{a2,b1,c1},{c2,b1,c1},...}
```

The resulting table would be

```
tab3 = {{a1,b1,c1,d1,f1,g1,...},{a1,b1,c1,d2,f2,g2,...},...}
```

My problem is that for the case of specific `tab1`, `tab2` Mathematica crashes when trying to compile `tab3`, Most likely this is due to the total length of `tab3` (it just quits kernel without any messages). In particular, it works if reducing the dimension of `tab1` by, for instance, 50 times. My question is how to fix this problem.  My machine: Mathematica 12.1@Windows10, Acer ConceptD7 Ezel, 16 Gb RAM, i7-10875H.

Please find the code defining an example `tab2` (in the code, it is called `TableDistributionNtoYZtempReduced`) below. Note that it is complicated, as in reality `tab2` is computed much less trivially. The dimensionality is controlled by the parameter `isimulval` (set to 10000):

```
MassParticleTest = 1.5;
mProdTomXratio2body = 0.3;
DecayType = "2-body";
mProd3Body1 = 0;
mProd3Body2 = 0;
mProd3Body3 = 0;
mproduct1 = 
  If[DecayType == "2-body", mProdTomXratio2body*MassParticleTest, 
   If[DecayType == "3-body", mProd3Body1]];
mproduct2 = 
  If[DecayType == "2-body", mProdTomXratio2body*MassParticleTest, 
   If[DecayType == "3-body", mProd3Body2]];
(*Number of rows in the table*)
isimulval = 10000;
(*Position of the point in coordinate space in terms of spherical \
coordinates*)
phVal[px_, py_] = 
  If[py > 0, 
   ArcCos[px/Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]], -ArcCos[px/Sqrt[px^2 + py^2]]];
thVal[px_, py_, pz_] = ArcCos[pz/Sqrt[px^2 + py^2 + pz^2]];
TableDistributionNtoYZtempReducedTemp = 
  Hold@Compile[{{tab, _Real, 2}, imax}, 
       Table[{thVal[tab[[i]][[1]], tab[[i]][[2]], tab[[i]][[3]]], 
         phVal[tab[[i]][[1]], tab[[i]][[2]]], tab[[i]][[4]], 
         thVal[tab[[i]][[5]], tab[[i]][[6]], tab[[i]][[7]]], 
         phVal[tab[[i]][[5]], tab[[i]][[6]]], tab[[i]][[8]]}, {i, 1, 
         imax, 1}]] /. DownValues@phVal /. DownValues@thVal // 
   ReleaseHold;
imax = 10000;
Block2BodyDistrAtRest := Block[{},
  nVectorParticle1 = Table[RandomPoint[Sphere[]], {i, 1, imax, 1}];
  nVectorParticles := 
   Hold@Compile[{{nVectorParticle1, _Real, 2}, mN, mX, mY, imax}, 
      Table[{Sqrt[((mN^2 + mX^2 - mY^2)/(2*mN))^2 - mX^2]
          nVectorParticle1[[i]][[1]], 
        Sqrt[((mN^2 + mX^2 - mY^2)/(2*mN))^2 - mX^2]
          nVectorParticle1[[i]][[2]], 
        Sqrt[((mN^2 + mX^2 - mY^2)/(2*mN))^2 - mX^2]
          nVectorParticle1[[i]][[3]], ((mN^2 + mX^2 - mY^2)/(
         2*mN)), -Sqrt[((mN^2 - mX^2 + mY^2)/(2*mN))^2 - mY^2]
           nVectorParticle1[[i]][[1]], -Sqrt[((mN^2 - mX^2 + mY^2)/(
            2*mN))^2 - mY^2]
           nVectorParticle1[[i]][[2]], -Sqrt[((mN^2 - mX^2 + mY^2)/(
            2*mN))^2 - mY^2] nVectorParticle1[[i]][[3]], ((
         mN^2 - mX^2 + mY^2)/(2*mN))}, {i, 1, imax, 1}]] // 
    ReleaseHold;
  nVectorParticlesmXmY = 
   nVectorParticles[nVectorParticle1, MassParticleTest, mproduct1, 
    mproduct2, imax]]
TableDistributionNtoYZtempReduced = 
  If[DecayType == "2-body", 
   TableDistributionNtoYZtempReducedTemp[Block2BodyDistrAtRest, 
    isimulval], 
   If[DecayType == "3-body", 
    TableDistributionNtoYZtempReducedTemp[Block3BodyDistrAtRest[imax],
      isimulval], 0]];
```

The same is true about `tab1` (called `TableHNLgridWithEN`). Its dimensionality is fixed and equal to 229190:

```
AzimuthalAcceptanceMotherParticle[thN_, xLongN_] = 0.16;
thGivenExperimentDetMin = 0.44;
thGivenExperimentDetMax = 0.88;
xLongToDecVolGivenExperiment = 60;
xLongNMaxGivenExperiment = 85;
NumberphN = 10;
RandomphNvalues[thN_, xLongN_] := RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, NumberphN]
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]
DefaultCCompiler[]
TableHNLgridTemp1 = 
   Flatten[ParallelTable[{thN, xLongN, 
      AzimuthalAcceptanceMotherParticle[thN, xLongN], 
      RandomphNvalues[thN, xLongN]}, {thN, 
      1.001 thGivenExperimentDetMin + 10^-5., 
      0.99 thGivenExperimentDetMax, (0.99 thGivenExperimentDetMax - \
(1.001 thGivenExperimentDetMin + 10^-5.))/12.}, {xLongN, 
      1.005 xLongToDecVolGivenExperiment, 
      xLongNMaxGivenExperiment, (xLongNMaxGivenExperiment - 
         1.005 xLongToDecVolGivenExperiment)/40.}], {1, 
     2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
TableHNLgridTemp12 = TableHNLgridTemp1[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];
TableHNLgridTemp13 = TableHNLgridTemp1[[All, 4]];
ENvalues = Table[10^EN, {EN, Log10[1.1*MassParticleTest], 3.2, 0.07}];
TableHNLgridWithEN = 
   Flatten[Table[{ENvalues[[k]], TableHNLgridTemp12[[i]][[1]], 
      TableHNLgridTemp12[[i]][[2]], TableHNLgridTemp12[[i]][[3]], 
      TableHNLgridTemp13[[i]][[j]]}, {k, 1, Length[ENvalues], 1}, {i, 
      1, Length[TableHNLgridTemp12], 1}, {j, 1, NumberphN, 1}], {1, 2,
      3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The code which computes `tab3` (which has the dimensionality isimulval*229190 in the example reproducing the problem) and fails:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 2}}, 
   Table[Join[x, Compile`GetElement[y, i]], {i, 1, Length[y]}], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
TableHNLgridWithENfinal = 
   Flatten[cf[TableHNLgridWithEN, 
     TableDistributionNtoYZtempReduced], {1, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: An element of tab1 or tab too takes: 168Bytes (you can get this by ByteCount). The dimension of tab3 is: isimulval*229190. Therefore, tab3 takes: 385039200000Bytes. I think for this you would need a super computer.

Comment: hint, `Outer[Join,tab1,tab2,1]//Flatten[#,1]&` could get tab3.

Comment: @DanielHuber : is it possible to reduce the capacity of the elements?

Comment: Could you try to do things lazily? For example, write a function `tab3elem[x_,y_] := ...` such that you would expect `tab3elem[i,j] == tab3[[i,j]]`, but without actually computing `tab3`. You might find the `LazyTuples` package referenced at the start of the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109598/lazy-form-of-tuples-outer-to-loop-over-list-of-lists) relevant, but I'm not sure exactly how. It also might just be easy enough to write your own function! I guess the question is: what are you trying to do with `tab3`?

Comment: It depends on the values of a1,a2,..d1,....

Comment: @thorimur : I want to use its elements for making the transformation of elements of another table.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow. What does that mean? And does it mean lazy evaluation is a candidate strategy here?